# Increment value in each partition based on change in one column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column (number) for each partition in PySpark DataFrame which gets incremented when a change occurs in the column year.

Original data:

```
name period year 
A    1      2010
A    1      2010
A    1      2011
A    1      2013
B    1      2018
B    1      2019
C    2      2018
C    2      2018
C    2      2019
```

Expected Output:

```
name period year  number
A    1      2010  1
A    1      2010  1
A    1      2011  2
A    1      2013  3
B    1      2018  1
B    1      2019  2
C    2      2018  1
C    2      2018  1
C    2      2019  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the sample dataframe you provided:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [{"name":'A', "period":1, "year":2010},
        {"name":'A', "period":1, "year":2010},
        {"name":'A', "period":1, "year":2011},
        {"name":'A', "period":1, "year":2013},
        {"name":'B', "period":1, "year":2018},
        {"name":'B', "period":1, "year":2019},
        {"name":'C', "period":2, "year":2018},
        {"name":'C', "period":2, "year":2018},
        {"name":'C', "period":2, "year":2019}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

Using the window function to partition the dataframe and then dense_rank based on that partitioning:

```
window = (Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.col('year').asc()))

df = df.withColumn('number', F.dense_rank().over(window)).orderBy("name", "year")
```

Result:

[image]